# Differential Equation of nth order and its Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Source: Linear Ordinary Differential Equations, book by E.D.Coddington]

I am looking to show that $\psi$ satisfies a linear homogenous equation given in the image with $b_1=0$.
There is a use of Wronskian in this question as the hint suggests and using that hint I have to proceed but I am unable to do so. So, please help me in proving this statement.

Source: Linear Ordinary Differential Equations, book authored by E.A.Coddington.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the usual shift in a polynomial that renders the second-highest coefficient zero, moves the center of gravity of the roots to the origin. Sometimes this is considered the normal form.

The claim uses that $D(e^{\lambda x}y(x))=e^{λx}(Dy(x)+λy(x))$ so that conversely
$$
e^{λx}Dy(x)=(D-λ)(e^{λx}(x))\implies e^{λx}p(D)y(x)=p(D-λ)(e^{λx}y(x))
$$
and
$$
p(D-λ)=(D-λ)^n+a_1(D-λ)^{n-1}+...=[D^n-nλD^{n-1}+...]+a_1[D^{n-1}+...]+...
$$
so that indeed for $nλ=a_1$ the coefficients for $D^{n-1}$ cancel.